# How to debug a db4o database running on an Android app

Tags: java, android, db4o

I have an Android app that uses a db4o database, and I would like to query this database while running my application. I have already installed OME (ObjectManager Enterprise) plugin on Eclipse, but I don't know how to connect it to my Android db4o database.

Has anyone been able to do this successfully? I'm not even sure if there is a way to access my Android app's data while the program is running.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid, there is no direct way to do this. You have to copy database from your android emulator to your machine and then query the db using OME
http://tracker.db4o.com/browse/OMJ-184

Answer (score 0):

i am using "db4o object manager 7.4". you can download https://code.google.com/p/db4o-om/downloads/detail?name=%24objectmanager-%207.4-java.zip&can=2&q=